# POST request error when app goes to background

Tags: ios, upload, nsurlsessiondatatask

Is it expected behavior for a POST request in URLSessionDataTask to have an error `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost` `-1005` when the app goest to the background during the request?

For example, during a POST web service request, the user taps the home button, waits for 5 seconds, comes back to the app and then the request returns with an error `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`.

Comment: Related info: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/872